# PHP script newline on linux

Tags: php, linux

I usually use PHP to create dynamic web pages, now I need to write a script on linux that is similar to an old one I wrote for my website and I don't want to rewrite the whole thing in python.

My problem is simple, I know that '\n' is the newline character for linux, but this doesn't work:

```
echo 'hello world\n';
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please also read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: In a single quoted string only quotes are unescaped. use double quotes instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this for linux:

```
echo 'hello world'."\n";
```

or this (works on any OS):

```
echo 'hello world'.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, escape characters like `\n` are only interpreted if the string is surrounded with double quotes, so try:

```
echo "hello world\n";
```